# Regular expression to evaluate password string

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

I'm working on a little project, I need to evaluate a string of only four characters[I can write little bit REs, but this one got me.].
I need to write a regular expression that will must match `1 upper case` word, `1 lower case` word, `one digit` and one random character like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. order doesn't matter in the string.

Here are some case strings that it should pass or fail.

```
Valid words: Abn1, GGh3, 89jK….

Invalid words: abcd, 112a, abDb, 2Ab, 4, AA, ….
```

any help or heads up appreciated.

Comment: This is sort of unclear, does it mean the strings should contain at least 4 characters? Words or *strings*? Try [`\b(?=[a-z\d]*[A-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)(?=[A-Z\d]*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}`](https://regex101.com/r/ej2o4T/1). Or, if the whole string should match, [`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/C1HkYT/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, string must contain 4 characters only, neither more nor less

Comment: @downvoter, your good thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muultiple lookaheads is your answer

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\b

(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z])    # string contains any lowercase character
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z])    # string contains any uppercase character
(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])    # string contains any digit
[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}           # 4 characters, since the 4th is  the type that can fit in any of the three
```

If the string is from a single input (like a 4-character textbox, you should should replace the word boundaries (`\b`) with `^` and `$`, like

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: I've put this RE to environment, and it doesn't seem working.
http://regexr.com/3fcvp

Comment: @Mubin The single-input version is if you were to have a textbox you intended for someone to enter only these 4 characters in, the top version detects these patterns in larger texts. It depends what your intent is.

Comment: why multiple look aheads? its driving me crazy not knowing the "why"

Comment: @Carine Because a single lookahead with alternation will pass if even one of the conditions are met.

Comment: @RegularJoe I wish i knew what that meant LOL...  pretty much i spent a lot of time trying to find a way to use the brackets with a +  but it was order dependent... isn't there way to tell it these things... in any order?

Comment: @Carine THe answer would be too detailed for a comment but i'll try `[abc]+` is a *character class* and permits any of those three letters any number of times (more than 0) so `accc` would work. `(abc)+` is a group so would permit  It would permit `abc` one or more times, so `abcabcabc...abc`.

Answer (score -1):

Single RegExp is not a good way to do that.

The best solution to just check your rules in the loop iterating characters.

As an option you can write 3 simple Regexps for each rule, instead of one big Regexp.

Comment: One regular expression is an ideal solution for this actually. The expression is pretty simple as expressions go.

Comment: I prefer to keep each test in separate function - to be able to modify each test separately later

Comment: But I needed single `RE` to achieve this and @cfqueryparam's answer worked for me